# show a hidden div after form submit

Tags: javascript, html

I save the data using POST method from a form.
After the data has been saved, page reloaded, I want to show a hidden div in the page.

```
onsubmit="showHide(this); return false;"
```

shows the specified div but does not save data.

any ideas?

LE:

to make it more complicated: the form that trigges the page reload is on the div that i want to re-show. initialy i make the div visible with:

```
<a class="articleLink" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='$("#ModAdd<?php echo $rrows['id_']; ?>").show("slow");'></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to display the div **after** the reload.
`onsubmit` will display it right away (on the same page). So check if the `$_POST` is set in php after reloading the site and then display the `div`

**Example**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)):
?>
    <div>Saved successfully</div>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

No data will be sent since you have a `return false;` in your `onSubmit`.

If you want the user to stay on the same page, you'll need **Ajax**.
Else, you have to show your `div` on the page that receives the data from your form.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this after reloading the page, instead of **onsubmit**:

```
$POST = $POST['myPost'];
      $Message = '<script type="text/javascript">';
      $Message .= 'document.getElementById("' . $IDName . '").style.display="block";'; // Show the hidden DIV
      $Message .= 'document.getElementById("' . $IDName . '").innerHTML="' . $POST . '";'; // Output POST value
      $Message .= '</script>';
echo $Message;
```

Comment: is ok, but I changed a bit the problem