# Display hidden div after successful form upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using a shortcode as part of my membership setup which allows users to upload files directly to their contact record in my CRM. This displays a multi-upload form which I have then styled:

[image: Image 001]

Once the files are uploaded the page refreshes and a success message appears. On refresh I also need to display a hidden div (`#hiddendiv`) underneath the success message.

From what I've read there is a **JS/PHP** combination that could potentially achieve this (such as [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443397/show-a-hidden-div-after-form-submit) - although this is quite vague and difficult to adapt).

Can anyone assist me/point me in the right direction to achieve this?

Comment: "On refresh" use session to store the uploading status

Comment: After reload the page means you can set session or pass some parameter and add condition in php to display

Comment: Depending on your access on the form, check if the element of the success message is there and then display the `div` via JS

Comment: Just don't put the `<div>` in the HTML code - `echo` it out with PHP when your form submission has been validated and processed. `<?php if($everything_is_hunky_dory) echo "<div>with a message</div>"; ?>`

Answer (score 2):

Since your form page is refreshing then you obviously not using AJAX, therefore instead of putting the div as html what you can do is echo a assign a variable initially it should be empty then, then echo that variable where you wanna show the div, this will echo empty message at the begging... then upon successfully validating your form and on success then assign the content of that div to the empty variable once the page loads its gonna show the div content u just assign

```
<?php

        $hiddenDiv = "";

            if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])){

                //validate what you need to validate on 


                //On success assign value to hidden div



                $hiddenDiv="<div class=\"whatever\">What ever dv content you need to display</div>";
            }


    ?>


    <!-- the place you wanna show the div -->


    <?= $hiddenDiv?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jquery [switch class](https://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/). This will allow you to do CSS transitions to make the appearance of the element smoother. This could be part of 'a' ajax response.

You could also just do something as simple as

```
$('#hiddendiv').css({"display":"inline"})
```

EDIT ** changed the to 'a' in reference to ajax.

Comment: ... what makes you think the form is being submitted via AJAX?

Comment: `Once the files are uploaded the page refreshes` this does not sound like ajax to me

Comment: I was saying it could be part of an ajax response. I did put the.... by mistake. Should have been A. I will alter this to save confusion.

Comment: Which still doesn't alter the fact that the page is being refreshed - ergo, not using AJAX at all, so **what** is the trigger you're using to activate the `display` toggle?

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['whatever'])
{
$display='';
}
else
{
$display='none';
}

?>
<div style='display:<?=$display?>'></div>
```